# Possible to implement ControllerFactory and IHttpControllerActivator in MVC4 for dependency injection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api, controller-factory

I've implemented both the ControllerFactory for Mvc Controllers and IHttpControllerActivator for WebApi Controllers like so:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(
                new MvcCompositionRoot());

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(
                    typeof(IHttpControllerActivator),
                    new WebApiCompositionRoot());
```

but when I send a request for the WebApi it throws an exception as the ControllerFactory is trying to resolve it. 
The exception is: **"The controller for path '/SiteName/Account' was not found or does not implement IController."**

I've tried it as a "Get" with (query string) parameters and without, but the result is the same.

Is it possible to implement both in the same project?

Comment: Are you sure it's Web API? `IController` is part of MVC, not Web API. Web API uses `IHttpController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, me just being an idiot and missing "Api" from '/SiteName/Api/Account'